# How to move a button from its a layout parent to another on android java?

Tags: java, android, animation

I'm trying to make a simple game for practice on android, but I need a generic function which can help me to move a button from its layout parent to another, so the user should be able to look the animation of that, please can you help me?

Comment: here you can see a list of animations possible in constraint layout :https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/tree/master/ConstraintLayoutExamples

Comment: thanks, I'm going to try it